# Error invoking user-provided 'pageFunction': Error: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures

Tags: javascript, json, stringify, apify

I am using [Apify](http://www.apify.com), a headless browser service to write web scraping [crawlers](https://www.apify.com/docs/crawler), which are Javascript.

I am attempting to collect the article content for hundreds of articles I have published on a blog.

The crawler works by [specifying](https://www.apify.com/docs/crawler#startUrls), in Apify's web interface, the start and list pages, which are paginated indexes containing links to the articles, as well as the URL pattern for target articles it should crawl from there...

[image]

In my choice of names...

- START: https://www.example.com/author/myname
- LIST: https://www.example.com/author/myname/page/[\d+]
- DETAIL: https://www.example.com/[\d+]*/[\d+]*/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*.html$

Here is the crawler code...

```
function pageFunction(context) {

    // Called on every page the crawler visits, use it to extract data from it
    var $ = context.jQuery;

    // If page is START or a LIST,
    if (context.request.label === 'START' || context.request.label === 'LIST') {

        context.skipOutput();

        // First, gather LIST page
        $('a.page-numbers').each(function() {
            context.enqueuePage({
                url: /*window.location.origin +*/ $(this).attr('href'),
                label: 'LIST'
            });
        });

        // Then, gather every DETAIL page
        $('h3>a').each(function(){
            context.enqueuePage({
                url: /*window.location.origin +*/ $(this).attr('href'),
                label: 'DETAIL'
            });
        });

    // If page is actually a DETAIL target page
    } else if (context.request.label === 'DETAIL') {

        result = {
            "title": $('h1')
        };

    }
    return result;
}
```

I think this construction may be somewhat correct.

From the START and LIST, this correctly identifies the right URLs to crawl, that is not the issue. Apify behaviour is that [pageFunction](https://www.apify.com/docs/crawler#pageFunction) fires for each page for which data is to be extracted. I am testing by aiming to extract only each page's `H1` tag.

The issue is that for each one (ie. when [pageFunction](https://www.apify.com/docs/crawler#pageFunction) executes), rather than return the `H1` tag, the crawler is returning...

```
Error invoking user-provided 'pageFunction': Error: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

I have read about [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) I do not fully understand the issue.

Comment: `"title": $('h1')` should probably be `"title": $('h1').text()`

Comment: If you meant to get the h1 text `$('h1')` won't do that. That is more than likely just the wrapping object (ie jQuery in browser, cheerio in nodejs, or some other library).  Which probably holds a cyclic reference (ie a reference to itself). To get the text would probably be something like `$('h1').text()` depending on the library being used.

Comment: This is the solution, yes. I was not correctly referencing the H1 jquery selector. Thank you.